# One time alert dialogue in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

How do I only show an alert dialogue once? I want to have an alert dialogue appear when the user first loads a screen to show an instruction. Once the dialogue is dismissed, I do not want it to appear again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [Shared Preferences](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shared_preferences)

1. When launching the app, get the value from shared pref (Ex: isFirstLoaded). If isFirstLoaded == true then show the dialog.
2. When the dialog is dismissed, set isFirstLoaded = false and save to shared preferences.

Below is an example (please note that the example doesn't handle the dismiss event when tapping on Back key).

Add shared_preferences to your pubspec.yaml

> shared_preferences: ^0.5.1+1

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyStatelessApp());
}

class MyStatelessApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Stateless Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: StatelessWidgetDemo(),
    );
  }
}

class StatelessWidgetDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  final keyIsFirstLoaded = 'is_first_loaded';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () => showDialogIfFirstLoaded(context));
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Flutter Stateless Demo'),
            ),
            body: Center(
              child: Text('Hello'),
            )));
  }

  showDialogIfFirstLoaded(BuildContext context) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    bool isFirstLoaded = prefs.getBool(keyIsFirstLoaded);
    if (isFirstLoaded == null) {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          // return object of type Dialog
          return AlertDialog(
            title: new Text("Title"),
            content: new Text("This is one time dialog"),
            actions: <Widget>[
              // usually buttons at the bottom of the dialog
              new FlatButton(
                child: new Text("Dismiss"),
                onPressed: () {
                  // Close the dialog
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  prefs.setBool(keyIsFirstLoaded, false);
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I understand the logic but I don't know how to implement exactly. Any chance you could provide example code? Thank you!

Comment: Let me add an example

Comment: This did it. Thank you very much. I had to make a few adjustments. Like setting a barrierdismissable. But I was able to inject this properly. Thanks you very much and well done!